# og:image Works Unpredictably on WordPress Theme

Tags: wordpress, facebook-opengraph

When attempting to share a page on FB, many images seem to only appear AFTER running the page that contains the image through the debugger first. Additionally, the debugger seems to throw different errors for the same page in some cases, even though I've made absolutely no changes to the page. Sometimes it tells me the image url cannot be found, and after clicking on "Scraped URL:" or "Graph API: the image url is found and the image then appears in the debugger?! However, nothing seems to happen consistently and it is very difficult to replicate these issues.

I tried unsuccessfully to post the code here, however, I'm using a modified version of a script provided by Chad Von Lind (http://vonlind.com/?p=539).

Sample pages (that did not display an image until after they were submitted to the debugger):
http://greatmomentsinparenting.com/photos/warning-parents-keep-out/
http://greatmomentsinparenting.com/photos/12-hours-in-a-car/

I don't understand why the images appear sometimes, and not at other times. Is it a caching issue? Does it take time for the image to show up in the cache for a newly published page? Can I force FB to cache the image on the first try? Or is it because I'm using a dynamic image url? And by the way, the image sizes are 203x203 pixels.

Thanks!

Comment: OK, thanks to Brian's help and Mediatemple's support, I'm gaining a better understanding of the issue. I checked my MT server log and can only find 200 and 206 response codes for FB requests. So, something is blocking the FB requests before they can hit the server (resulting in a 502 or 503 in FB's debugger). Otherwise, the 502's and 503's would show up in my log (unless FB is actually failing to make the request). Mediatemple is still looking into the issue.

Comment: As it turns out the issue was on Mediatemple's side (firewall): https://forum.mediatemple.net/topic/6759-facebook-503-502-same-html-different-servers-different-results/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's media temple. I have been working with them for weeks to fix it.

[Facebook 503 502 Same html different servers different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609929/facebook-503-502-same-html-different-servers-different-results)

Comment: Thanks Brian, but I'm not so sure this is the same issue. I paste exactly the SAME url into the debugger every time and get different results... even though nothing has changed on the website. It's really maddening.

Comment: I ran your urls and got the same results as all my domains. MT just emailed me today saying FB won't respond their request so far. Please create a support ticket at MT and subscribe to http://goo.gl/wGH5m the more preasure we can apply the better.

Comment: Thanks Brian... I actually did yesterday, and they told me it is a known issue and provided a few links-- one of which is the one you kindly provided. I will certainly follow it. Thanks again!